# Error while doing set_difference: Variable result is not a structure

Tags: c++, stl, set, set-difference

i had declared a set variable outside a function globally.

```
std::set<std::string> s1;
std::set<std::string> s2;   
std::set<std::string> intersect;    
std::set<std::string> _result_; //here is the declaration
```

Now i try to populate that structure inside a function.

```
s1.insert("1-1");
s2.insert("1-1");
std::set_intersection( s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),std::insert_iterator< std::set<std::string> >( intersect, intersect.begin() ) );
    std::set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),std::inserter(_result_, _result_.end()));//this is where the error is coming.
```

I get this compilation error:

```
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 6572: Error: Variable result is not a structure.
```

edit:

the removal of underscore didnot work.
i tried now with :

```
std::set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),std::insert_iterator< std::set<std::string> >(result_, result_.end() ) );
```

This gives me another compilation error.:

```
"/export/SunStudio/SUNWspro/prod/include/CC/Cstd/./algorithm.cc", line 2161: Error: Overloading ambiguity between "std::copy<__rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::string>>>(__rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, __rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::string>>)" and "copy<__rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::string>>>(__rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, __rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::string>>)".
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 6572:     Where: While instantiating "std::set_difference<__rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, __rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::string>>>(__rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, __rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, __rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, __rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::string>>)".
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 6572:     Where: Instantiated from non-template code.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier - try with a variable name without a leading underscore

Comment: tried that but the problem still appears.

Comment: The `std::copy` error suggests something different is going on here. Are you trying to copy from a `std::multimap` to a `std::set` (like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8560322/78845))? You really need to supply us with the *actual* code you are trying to build!

Comment: Your edit describes a new issue, which should be posted as a new question, were it not [already asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635186/). SO uses a Q&A, rather than forum, format. If you have distinct questions, they should be posted as such.

Answer (score 2):

[This code compiles for me.](http://ideone.com/z3qsS)

Perhaps your compiler is complaining about your underscore usage? Since it says:

> Variable **`result`** is not a structure.

Whereas you declared `_result_`.

See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) (as recommended by [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat)).

Comment: as i had updated .i removed the underscore and tried another method of inserting.even that did not work.i also changed the name to "myresult" even that did not work.

Comment: Can you provide a short but complete example? I can't reproduce the error with the code you've given, even with SUNPro.

Comment: the problems seems that we have our own set_difference defined in our source code. in algorithm.cc as you can see teh compilation error.i am just trying to figure a way out to use only standard c++ set_difference.but i am not knowing how to do it.

Comment: `SUNWspro/prod/include/CC/Cstd/algorithm.cc` is SunPRO's implementation of the algorithms from the Standard Library. The error is in one of your 6572+ lines of code. This is why I asked you to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I can't help you otherwise.

Comment: I am afraid i can't give you an example.coz when i tried the same line in a sample c++ program it compiled perfectly:(

Comment: Now you see *my* problem! I'm afraid without an example, I cannot help any further.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6134/discussion-between-peter-and-johnsyweb)

Answer (score 0):

> `std::set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),std::inserter(_result_, _result_.end()));`

Add type parameter in inserter definition:

```
std::set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), std::inserter< std::set<std::string> >(_result_, _result_.end()));
```