# Error: Overloading ambiguity between "std::copy

Tags: c++, stl, inserter

I have a code like below:

```
#include<set>
#include<iterator>

std::set<std::string> s1;
std::set<std::string> s2;   
std::set<std::string> myresult;

void some_func() {
    std::set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),std::inserter(myresult,myresult.begin()));
}
```

This gives me compilation error:

> /export/SunStudio/SUNWspro/prod/include/CC/Cstd/./algorithm.cc", line 2161: Error: Overloading ambiguity between "std::copy<__rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::string>>>(__rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, __rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::string>>)" and "copy<__rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::string>>>(__rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, __rwstd::__rb_tree<std::string, std::string, __rwstd::__ident<std::string, std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>::const_iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::string>>)".

Comment: This must be specific to SunStudio: I just compiled your code  with my C++ compiler on mac, and it compiled without a single warning .

Comment: This smells of classical ADL/Koenig lookup problem.

Comment: Could it be a compiler thing? My g++ 4.5.2 compiles your snippet just fine (I've added an `#include<algorithm>`).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Or perhaps your compiler has a problem specific to _it_ that makes the above code pass. ;)

Comment: Apparently, it's a [very common problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634234/error-while-doing-set-difference-variable-result-is-not-a-structure) today.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add

```
#include<algorithm>
```

to your code.