# what is the alternative to set_difference in c++

Tags: c++, stl, set-difference

I have two `sets`.they have some common elements(sets have strings as thier elements)

like :
`set1` has elements

```
"1-2","1-1","3-4"
```

`set2` has elements

```
"1-2","1-3","3-4"
```

i want take out the values "1-1" into one set 
and value "1-3" into another.
i know `set_difference` will do the job for me.But some how i am facing some problems with `set_ifference`.please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634234/error-while-doing-set-difference-variable-result-is-not-a-structure)

Is there any alternative to using `set_difference` achieving the same reults?

Comment: The alternative is ... to fix the issue you have with `set_difference`.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative would be to roll your own, as [Kerrek SB did in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8561274/78845) to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8559820/78845).

That said, it would be far better to understand and to solve the problem you have with [`std::set_difference()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/), rather than working around it.

For instance, were I getting long compiler errors involving `templates` on the line containing `set_difference`, I would break this up into a small series of separate, simple statements, which will make pinpointing the error much easier:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    typedef std::set<std::string> set_of_strings;
    set_of_strings s1, s2, result;

    s1.insert("1-2");
    s1.insert("1-1");
    s1.insert("3-4");

    s2.insert("1-2");
    s2.insert("1-3");
    s2.insert("3-4");

    // Temporary variables for debugging only
    set_of_strings::iterator s1_begin = s1.begin();
    set_of_strings::iterator s1_end = s1.end();
    set_of_strings::iterator s2_begin = s2.begin();
    set_of_strings::iterator s2_end = s2.end();
    set_of_strings::iterator result_end = result.end();
    std::insert_iterator<set_of_strings> result_inserter = std::inserter(result, result_end);

    std::set_difference(s1_begin, s1_end,
                        s2_begin, s2_end,
                        result_inserter);

    std::copy(result.begin(),
              result.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

The compiler would then check that each of `set_difference`'s five parameters is of the type that it expects and would allow me to see quite quickly which of them is causing the issue because they're all declared in separate statements.

Once I'd solved the issue, I'd refactor to remove the unnecessary variables, of course.