# Template function written for finding multimap intersectionof written one part of string as pointer and rest correctly

Tags: c++

I have written a code for finding intersection of two multimap which will compare 
values  related to key and fetch us a map containing a comman elements (combination 
of key and value) from two map. This is displaying one part of string as pointer 
and rest as usual.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdio.h>

template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class OutputIterator>

/* templet function to return common elements od two map  */

OutputIterator map_intersection ( InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
        InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2,
        OutputIterator result )
{
    while (first1!=last1 && first2!=last2)
    { 
        if (*first1<*first2) ++first1;
        else if (*first2<*first1) ++first2;
        else {  
            const char*abc= new char[15];
            const char*def= new char[15];
            /* Below code inserts the common element in result map */ 
            if(strcmp((first1->second.c_str()),(first2->second.c_str()))==0)
            {                                                                   
                result.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>(first1->first,first1->second));
                ++first1;
                ++first2;
            }
            else
            {
                ++first1;
                ++first2;  
            } 
        } 
    }
    return result;

}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::multimap<string, string> m;
    std::multimap<string, string>::iterator it2;
    std::multimap<string, string> intersection;
    std::multimap<string, string> common;
    std::multimap<string, string> it3;

    cout <<"Making Map m "<<endl;
    m.insert(pair< string, string>("1 2"," 22 3" ));
    m.insert(pair< string, string>("1 2"," 21 4" ));
    m.insert(pair< string, string>("2 1"," 31 3" ));

    cout <<"Making Map c "<<endl;
    std::multimap<string, string> c;
    c.insert(pair< string, string>("1 2"," 22 3" ));
    c.insert(pair< string, string>("1 2"," 22 4" ));
    c.insert(pair< string, string>("2 1"," 31 3" ));

    cout << "Elements in common map are: " << endl;
    it3=map_intersection (m.begin(), m.end(), c.begin(), c.end(),common);

    cout << " am i out of the map_intersection loop " << endl;
    cout << " size of common map is : " << it3.size()<< endl;
    for(it2 =it3.begin(); it2!=it3.end();it2++)
    {   
        cout << "first common element is : " <<  
            cout << it2->first << " " << it2->second <<"  " << endl;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Expected output :

```
1 2   22 3
2 1   31 3
```

Output on console:

```
0x4483c41 2   22 3
0x4483c42 1   31 3
```

Comment: "Template function written for finding multimap intersectionof written one part of string as pointer and rest correctly": StackOverflow should offer a bronze badge for the most convoluted and at the same time zero-information-content title.

Comment: Nitpick: C++ actually doesn’t know what a “template function” is (although even the standard mentions it by accident, if I recall correctly). You mean a “function template”. There’s a small but fundamental conceptual difference.

Comment: There was a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8561274/596781) a while ago, check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code:

```
cout << "first common element is : " <<  
    cout << it2->first << " " << it2->second <<"  " << endl;
    ^^^^
```

You are outputting `cout` itself to `cout`, which causes the hex value to be printed. You need to either remove `cout` from the second line, or make these two separate statements.

The reason that the hex value gets printed is that `basic_ios` has an `operator void*` which returns a pointer. This pointer is passed to the overload of `basic_ostream::operator<<` which prints a pointer.

Comment: Thanks interjay , that was a mistake i overlooked . Thanks a lot

Comment: @mikeNakis Dude everyone is not a shakespeare as you , but i would rather try to be more informative in writting the heading , sorry if inconvenience caused .

Comment: @konard Rudolph Thanks for your effort .. Regards

Comment: @kerrek SB ... Thanks for your effort .. Regards