# Comparing two multimap objects in c++

Tags: c++, stl

i need to compare two multimap objects to find out whether they are equal or not

i know by using std::equal we can compare two vector object equality but is it possible to use this algorithm for comparing to multimap objects?

```
typedef std::multimap<std::string, std::string> HeaderMap;
HeaderMap _map,_secMap;


_map.insert(HeaderMap::value_type("A", "a"));
_map.insert(HeaderMap::value_type("B", "b"));

_secMap.insert(HeaderMap::value_type("A", "a"));
_secMap.insert(HeaderMap::value_type("B", "b"));



**std::equal(_map.begin(),_map.end(),_secMap.begin()); // is this true?**
```

if above code snippet is not true, how i can compare two multimap objects?(i don't ant to iterate objects and compare keys and values one by one)
thanks

Comment: You want us to run your code for you and tell you the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559820/compare-two-multimaps-c

Comment: FikTik :> no only suggest me a way that i use it to compare to multimap objects.if their content are equal return true else return flase.

Comment: Jonathan Potter :> these are not same questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare them with [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/operator_cmp):

```
map_ == secMap_;
```

This will internally compare elements one by one until the first unequal one is found. There is no way of avoiding that. Here is a working example:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  typedef std::multimap<std::string, std::string> HeaderMap;

  HeaderMap m1, m2, m3;

  m1.insert(HeaderMap::value_type("A", "a"));
  m1.insert(HeaderMap::value_type("B", "b"));

  m2.insert(HeaderMap::value_type("A", "a"));
  m2.insert(HeaderMap::value_type("B", "b"));

  m3.insert(HeaderMap::value_type("A", "a"));
  m3.insert(HeaderMap::value_type("B", "b"));
  m3.insert(HeaderMap::value_type("C", "c"));


  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << (m1==m2) << " " << (m1==m3) << std::endl;    
}
```

Output:

> true false

Bear in mind that names with leading underscores are reserved for the implementation so you should not use them.